# Margin in SeekbarPreference

Tags: android, layout

I'm using preferences to create a typical settings fragment. Everything is as expected except for the `SeekBarPreference` which seems to come with a default padding/margin, making it look indented ahead of the lines above it.

Is there a way to customize this margin?
[image]

Comment: could you put your xml here, or any code part that manipulates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps;

```
android:paddingStart="0dp"
```

or this

```
seekBar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Used it within one of the SeekBarPreference, no difference unfortunately.

Comment: also you seek bar seem out of screen. Did you put wrap content?

Comment: It's not out of screen, the screenshot I have is just cut off